# how to identify the organization behind a given IP address?

Tags: ip, python

I have a large `dataframe` as follows (fake data below):

```
ip     
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
```

Given the large quantity of `ip` adresses in my data, I would like to merge them with an **offline** dataset that would tell me for each address:

- organization name
- street
- city

Is it possible to do so from python without hitting some `api` limits?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.iana.org/whois?q=192.168.1.5 has the data you are looking for.

I'd use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [lxml](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) modules.

However, doing this kind of thing, it's best to assume you will get throttled or have null data.

**Edit:** Pardon my US-centric answer. There are other websites that allow queries from all the Regional Internet registries. https://www.whois.com/whois/151.101.64.81 would be an example. Websites are easy enough to scrape, but usually rate limit requests.

There are other services that provide an API style answer such as https://whoapi.com/. These usually cost money.

*Note:* I have not used any of these sites.

Comment: very nice!! thanks! can you just be a bit more explicit about which packages to use? i am fairly noob in this area. how can i pull the fields I want? and why iana only? what about RIPE?

Comment: and what do you mean by you will get throttled?

Comment: This isn't going to give the OP any information on which entity is using a particular ip address. It's going to tell the OP which organization is authoritative for the ip address (ARIN, APNIC, etc.) and what type of net block it is (Direct Allocation, Direct Assignment, etc.)

Comment: @joeqwerty Agreed the information is spotty at best. Error handling for lack of info is a must with this type of information.

Comment: IANA is not a US-centric organization. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks for your input. do you have other ideas that I can try perhaps?

Comment: I don't. I don't think there's any way for you to find out that ip address X.X.X..X has been allocated/assigned to Acme Corp.